# Windows10でイヤホンを使うと動画の一時停止で音量が変わる

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, firefox, youtube

Windows10で動画を一時停止後再生すると音量が大きくなります。
音量がそれなりに大きくなってしまうため直したいのですが
手掛かりがなかなか見つかりませんでした

良く調べたらサウンド効果をオフにするという解決策をみつけましたが
プロパティに拡張というタブがないため問題を解決できませんでした
https://tips4life.me/youtube_bug_volume

どうしたらこの問題を直せますか？

環境はこうなっています：

- windows10
- YouTube
- Chrome, firefox 最新版

パソコンの種類は現在確認できませんが、DELLのものでした。

Comment: 通常、動画の一時停止しても音量が変化することはありません。パソコンの機種、動画再生ソフト等を追記すると、回答が得られるかもしれません。また、動画再生ソフトはいろいろありますから、フリーソフト（例えばVLC等）を実行して試して見てください。

Comment: @池田茂樹  今わかる範囲で環境を追記いたしました。ご助言ありがとうございます、VLCで試していますが問題の発生条件がわからないのでもう少しVLCでの動作確認に時間がかかりそうです。

Comment: プログラミングとは直接関連のない話題のようなので、オフトピック寄りの質問なのかなと思います。 / タイトルに「イヤホン」とありますが、スピーカーから直接再生している時には問題が起きないのでしょうか？ / YouTube (ブラウザ) や再生アプリ等の **アプリ単位** で変更されてしまうのか、もしくは **システムの設定** が変更されてしまう…のどちらでしょうか。

Comment: オフトピよりな気はしますが……サウンド効果の項目はおそらくPCに搭載されているサウンドカードのドライバによって表示されることがありますが、例えば最近のRealtekのドライバなんかではここには表示されずUWPの専用アプリが用意されていたりします。あるいはエフェクターアプリが入ってる場合などもあるんですがこの手のエントリはWin10なら一緒だと思ってしまって書かれているものが多く。。。

Comment: @cubick スピーカーでも一時停止してタスクバーのスピーカーの音量を上げたり下げたりしてから一時停止を解除すると、音量を全く変更していない（上げ下げするだけで最後は元の音量に戻す）のに音量が上がりしました。VLC, YouTubeで確認しました。

Comment: @hinaloe Realtekのほかにサウンドマネージャとしてdell audioというものが入っていましたが、そこにもサウンド効果はありませんでした。何か追記したほうがよいものがあれば教えてくださると幸いです。